# Customize the pos_tag of a word in spacy

Tags: python, spacy, pos-tagger

I am using **spacy** to work with the pos_tags of words in a statement and I want the word **select** to be read as a *verb* in all cases.  So, "I would like to select a brown shirt" and "select brown shirt" (regardless of the grammar) should both have select as verbs.

Is there any way to do that in spacy(python)?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to write your own function to get part of speech, which will override spaCy's in case of the word "select". 
Something along the lines of:

```py
def get_pos(tok):
    return tok.tag_ if (str(tok) != "select") \
           else "VB" # <- Return whatever POS tag you'd like.
```